# giving 777 permissions for media folder

Tags: security, importexport, media

we are using custom import export for uploading the products.

but when we gave 777 permission for "media" folder, than only it will upload the images.

otherwise we will get error while uploading.

so is it fine with giving 777 permissions for only "media" folder.

or is there any security problems will appear for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not directly an entry point for attackers, but it can be a security issue when someone already has access to your server.

It's pretty common to store information (stolen from the Server) encrypted in image files. With 777 permissions on the media folder any user on the Server can do this.